# Why do the color schemes in Vim use fewer colors?

Tags: colorscheme

I'm using both Neovim/Vim and VS Code.

With both editors using the gruvbox theme, I noticed Neovim/Vim use fewer colors than VS Code when using the same theme. I have the same issue with the solarized theme.

[image]

Is there any option to activate in Vim that will enable more colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean less colors than VS Code? This is an artifact of (n)vim’s regex/contains/follows-based syntax highlighter. VS Code uses [TextMate Grammars](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) which are inherently better for parsing language-elements. I think nvim was talking about switching to a [tree-sitter parser](http://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) (the work in progress is [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/9219)).

---

As Mass mentions, there are a number of js plugins which greatly extend the syntax highlighting for javascript. I’ve been happy with pangloss/vim-javascript from github.

VS Code also appears to be using rainbow parens, plugins for which exist in the vim ecosystem as well.

Comment: Worth mentioning there are a number of javascript syntax files which improve upon vim's built-in one.  Also, the vs code screenshot uses some type of rainbow parens.

Comment: That's true. I forgot to mention it.